# How to upload a Large CSV file really fast in Laravel

Tags: php, postgresql, csv, laravel-5.4

This question has been asked so many times , I have tried couple of way also but this time I am stuck since my requirement is bit specific . None of the generic methods worked for me .

**Details**

File Size = 75MB
Total Rows = 300000

**PHP Code**

```
     protected $chunkSize = 500;

   public function handle()
   {
      try {

            set_time_limit(0);
            $file = Flag::where('imported','=','0')
                     ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                     ->first();


            $file_path = Config::get('filesystems.disks.local.root') . '/exceluploads/' .$file->file_name;


            // let's first count the total number of rows
            Excel::load($file_path, function($reader) use($file) {
             $objWorksheet = $reader->getActiveSheet();
             $file->total_rows = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow() - 1; //exclude the heading
             $file->save();
            });


            $chunkid=0;
            //now let's import the rows, one by one while keeping track of the progress

            Excel::filter('chunk')
            ->selectSheetsByIndex(0)
            ->load($file_path)
            ->chunk($this->chunkSize, function($results) use ($file,$chunkid) {
              //let's do more processing (change values in cells) here as needed
               $counter = 0;
               $chunkid++;
               $output = new ConsoleOutput();
               $data =array();

                foreach ($results->toArray() as $row) 
                {
                            $data[] = array(
                                        'data'=> json_encode($row),
                                        'created_at'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                                        'updated_at'=> date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                                   );
                            //$x->save();
                            $counter++;

                  }

                DB::table('price_results')->insert($data);
                $file = $file->fresh(); //reload from the database
                $file->rows_imported = $file->rows_imported + $counter;
                $file->save();
                $countx = $file->rows_imported + $counter;
                echo "Rows Executed".$countx.PHP_EOL;
            },
            false
            );

            $file->imported =1;
            $file->save();

           echo "end of execution";
      }
        catch(\Exception $e)
        {
          dd($e->getMessage());
        }
   }
```

So the above Code runs really fast for the `10,000` rows CSV File.

But when I upload a larger CSV its not working .

My Only restriction here is that I have to use following logic to transform each row of the CSV to KeyPair value json data

```
foreach ($results->toArray() as $row) 
                    {
                                $data[] = array(
                                            'data'=> json_encode($row),
                                            'created_at'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                                            'updated_at'=> date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                                       );
                                //$x->save();
                                $counter++;

                      }
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated , Its been more than and Hour now and still only 100,000 rows have been inserted

I find this is really slow

**Database** : POSTGRES

Comment: If you're only ever loading a CSV file, then PHPExcel is a big overhead, because it's designed to support multiple file formats, and formatting, and other features that don't exist in a simple csv.... just use standard PHP [fgetcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) functionality instead

Comment: @MarkBaker the use case Has multiple file support thats why I used the plugin,Like excel and maybe PDF too

Comment: How to efficiently eat soup witth a fork though your nose.

Comment: @wildplasser with all due respect how would you handle this use case I am cluless hence I am here . But open to learn any new method

Comment: Well: your question looks like the XY problem. If you want to bulkload data, don't do this via a frontend. Instead, read the CSV-file directly from the file system.

Comment: @wildplasser Actually this is a CLI tool `php artisan import:excelfile`  its just the file name that I pull from one of the DB, and then I save the excel in some other db